# How to frame dynamic salesforce composite query by iterating array

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule4, mule-component

Below is my input and through which I need to frame composite query to Salesforce

```
    {
  "headerId": "123",
  "Status": "Created",
  "OrderId": "232323",
  "Code": "RE",
  "Line": [{
      "lineItemId": "HP-0000074009",
      "status": null
  },
  {
      "lineItemId": "HP-0000074010",
      "status": "y"
  }
  ]
}
```

but the challenge here is I have array(Line) in the input which I need to iterate and first use GET to get the Id from the object and then use that Id to update the status in Salesforce using PATCH, means my dwl for composite query should look like below, where I need to get the Id and then use it in PATCH but I am unable to frame it dynamically, so please help with the correct dwl in order to achieve this scenario.

```
    %dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    "allOrNone" : true,
    "compositeRequest" : [
  {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "/services/data/v53.0/query/?q=SELECT Id FROM Line_vod__c WHERE Name='HP-0000074009' AND Code_TPI__c='RE'",
    "referenceId": "LineId"
  },
  {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "/services/data/v53.0/query/?q=SELECT Id FROM Line_vod__c WHERE Name='HP-0000074010' AND Code_TPI__c='RE'",
    "referenceId": "LineId"
  },
  {
    "method": "PATCH",
    "url": "/services/data/v53.0/sobjects/Line_vod__c/@{LineId.records[0].Id}",
    "referenceId": "updateLine",
    "body": {
      "Status_TPI__c": "Open"
    }
  },
  {
    "method": "PATCH",
    "url": "/services/data/v53.0/sobjects/Line_vod__c/@{LineId.records[0].Id}",
    "referenceId": "updateLine",
    "body": {
      "Status_TPI__c": "Closed"
    }
  }
]
}
```

Comment: If you use an invented syntax for dynamic expressions please at least clarify it. That's not valid DataWeave syntax. And please don't use 'dwl' which is ambiguous. You should add to your question the expect output.

Answer (score 0):

Below script might help you.

```
 %dw 2.0
output application/json

---
{
    allOrNone : true,
    compositeRequest : flatten(payload.Line map ((item, index) -> 
       [{
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "/services/data/v53.0/query/?q=SELECT Id FROM Line_vod__c WHERE Name='" ++ item.lineItemId ++ "' AND Code_TPI__c='" ++  payload.Code ++ "'",
    "referenceId": "LineId"
  } , 
       {
    "method": "PATCH",
    "url": "/services/data/v53.0/sobjects/Line_vod__c/@{LineId.records[0].Id}",
    "referenceId": "updateLine",
    "body": {
      "Status_TPI__c": if(item.status == "y") "Closed" else "Open"
    }
       }]
    ))
}
```

Comment: can we make the reference Id dynamic because the same referenceId for both GET calls since our array size is 2, will it be taking the first GET call output all the time even for the second GET call ?

Comment: @subhash the problem is that your question doesn't has the expected output so we can only guess what you really want. This answer matches what you shared in your question. My educated guess is that you need to replace literal `@{LineId.records[0].Id}` with the expression `item.lineItemId`